# Odoo 10 : How to make a call to a function on a salary rule?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

I need to make a call function from the object `payslip`, named `salaryfunction`:

```
class HrNicPaySlip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.multi
    def salaryfunction(self):
       return 100.00
```

I need to call this function from the salary rule, like this:

```
result = payslip.salaryfunction()
```

But I get the following error when calculating the pay sheep:

> Wrong python code defined for salary rule

In the logs the error is:

> ValueError: : "'float' object is not callable" while evaluating u'result = payslip.salaryfunction()'

Could you please help with that?

I searched about some similar issue but without success

Some more information:

I want to call a function defined in my model that inherits from hr.payslip

```
class MyModelTest(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

  @api.multi
  def salaryfunction(self):
    return 100.00
```

In my salary rule I wrote the amount_python_compute :

```
result = payslip.salaryfunction()
```

Comment: I have never worked with salary rules. I am curious, where do you access to these salary rules? Are they different from the security rules? It looks like there is a special sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, after read all the code of the payslip model.

The payslip object used in the salary rule has a env variable reference, so the correct way to call a function of other model class is below (according to my example):

```
result = payslip.env['hr.payslip'].salaryfunction()
```

I hope this works to another dude

Answer (score 1):

To call the function `salaryfunction()` does not work with `payslip.salaryfunction()` because previously when declaring the dictionary of local variables where `'payslip': Payslips (employee.id, self, self.env)` is a special object, which does not allow access methods of that object.

I recommend you create a new local variable `'self': self` in the method `_get_base_local_dict` from class `hr.payslip`, this allows you to call the method in the salary rule like this `self.salaryfunction()` being `salaryfunction()` a method of the class `'hr.payslip'`.

Comment: For some reason, in Odoo 16, I couldn't use `result = payslip.env['hr.payslip'].salaryfunction()`. It didn't launch any error, didn't work either. I had to override `_get_base_local_dict` and then call in the rule `result = self.salaryfunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside your model('hr.payslip') you just need to call your function in this way `self.salaryfunction()` and if you are in other model call it in this way `self.env['hr.payslip'].salaryfunction()`, I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hello Juan and thank you fro your response. I get this error ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'self' is not defined" while evaluating
u"result = self.env['hr.payslip'].salaryfunction()", that is because I make the call from the rule

Comment: Please share with as more details of your rule definition, and what you really want to get with that, maybe there is a more interesting solution to your problem.

Comment: I want to call a function defined in my model that inherits from hr.payslip
class MyModelTest(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'
    

    @api.multi
    def salaryfunction(self):
        return 100.00

In my salary rule I wrote the amount_python_compute :
result = payslip.salaryfunction()